# How do I change the perl regex for code formatting?

Tags: c, linux, perl

I am trying to understand the below code. But I am not getting it.
Basically, the below code currently checks for if condition in a c or cpp file.

```
if ($perl_version_ok &&
    $line =~ /^\+(.*)\b($Constant|[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)\s*($Compare)\s*($LvalOrFunc)/) {
    # Throw error
}
```

> where Constant is any macro or any constant value; LvalOrFunc is any variable or function call; Compare is the operations like !=, == ,&& , etc

The if checks for codes like this `if(CONST_VALUE == x)`, where CONST_VALUE is some macros. In this case its true and goes inside if condition.

But I want to check for the opposite `if(x == CONST_VALUE )`, and then throw error.

Please help in understanding this piece of line and how to achieve the desired result.

**Note:**
The code is from linux kernel dir, available here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/checkpatch.pl

Line number of the code: 5483

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code **doesn't** check for `if(CONST_VALUE == x)`. As shown in the comments above the line in the source code

```
# comparisons with a constant or upper case identifier on the left
#   avoid cases like "foo + BAR < baz"
#   only fix matches surrounded by parentheses to avoid incorrect
#   conversions like "FOO < baz() + 5" being "misfixed" to "baz() > FOO + 5"
```

it checks for a plus sign followed by a `CONSTANT_VALUE == x`. The `\+` in the regex matches a plus sign.

```
$line =~ /^\+(.*)\b($Constant|[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)\s*($Compare)\s*($LvalOrFunc)/
      ^   ^ ^  ^  ^
      |   | |  |  |
binding   | |  |  word
operator  | |  |  boundary
      start |  |
  of string |  |
         plus  | 
        anything
```

Reverting the compared values should be easy:

```
($LvalOrFunc)\s*($Compare)\s*($Constant|[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Apparently it doesn't work for all cases. Also it messes up values of `lead, const, comp, to` variables in line 5485, and that creates false positives. Any idea how I can handle that?

Comment: Yes, `$1` corresponds to the first capture group start, i.e. the leftmost `(`. You have to fix the assignments.

Comment: Yes. But what I meant is given an example input line `if ( x == CONSTANT_VALUE )`  , I expect `$1:     if(  
$2: x 
$3: ==
$4: CONSTANT_VALUE`. But I am getting this `$1:     if(  
$2: x 
$3: x
$4:  ` Thats where I think there is something we're missing in the check?

Comment: As I said, the regex matches things after a `+`, not `if`. You might try to replace the `\+` with a `\s*if\(`, but I'm still not sure it will work under any circumstances.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! That kind of worked for me. I added additional checks to make it work always.